# Why does boost::asio::async_read fail to read the requested number of bytes?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I've got a problem where `boost::asio::async_read` fails on the second call, in a strange way:

```
std::atomic<error_code> ec(asio::error::would_block);
size_t len = 0;

// 1st call
asio::async_read(socket,
                 asio::buffer(buffer+X),
                 asio::transfer_exactly(512-X),
                 [&] (error_code const& err, size_t bytesTransferred)
                 {
                     len = bytesTransferred;
                     ec.store(err, std::memory_order_release);
                 }
);
/////// ... wait for read to complete ...
// 2nd call
asio::async_read(socket,
                 asio::buffer(buffer),
                 asio::transfer_exactly(512),
                 [&] (error_code const& err, size_t bytesTransferred)
                 {
                     len = bytesTransferred;
                     ec.store(err, std::memory_order_release);
                 }
);
```

The constant `X` is because I have some data already that I got in another way,
so the first read is smaller. Say X=364, then `bytesTransferred` will be 148 the first time around. My problem however is that the second read **again** returns 148 bytes, even though **that** read was for 512 bytes exactly.

I'm baffled. The second call doesn't have an error condition (I checked `err`). `bytesTransferred` is an argument passed by `aync_read` to me, and it's 148 bytes twice. The first time, it matches the `asio::transfer_exactly(148)` higher up on the stack .The second time the callstack clearly has a `asio::transfer_exactly(512)`. What is going on here?

It's particular to that second call, though, The third call again reads 512 bytes, but also gets 512 bytes.

[MCVE]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

#include <boost/asio/buffer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read.hpp>

// Minimal example, code that works has error checking removed. Class members turned itno globals etc.
namespace {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock(io_service);
    std::vector<char> data(512);
    boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 buffer(&data[0], data.size());
    unsigned read_counter = 1;
    std::atomic<unsigned> read_timeout;
}

boost::system::error_code openSocket(const std::string &server,
                                     const std::string &port)
{
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
    tcp::resolver::query query(server, port);
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;

    while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
    {
        sock.close();
        sock.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    }
    if (error)
    {
        std::cerr << "No route\n";
        sock.close(); // Would be wrong to leave it open.
    }
    return error;
}

int read(size_t bytesNeeded)
{
    size_t buffer_len = boost::asio::buffer_size(buffer);
    size_t byteShift = buffer_len - bytesNeeded; // Read into back of buffer.

    const int timeoutSeconds = 10;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer deadline(io_service);
    deadline.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(timeoutSeconds)); // This will reset any outstanding timer
    read_counter += 2; // If we'd use +1, after 4 billion cycles it would reset to 0
    read_timeout.store(0, std::memory_order_release); // 0 = no timeout.
    unsigned read_counter_copy = read_counter; // Can't capture global.
    deadline.async_wait([read_counter_copy](boost::system::error_code const&) {
        // read_timeout is very intentionally captured by value - timeout events are numbered
        read_timeout.store(read_counter_copy, std::memory_order_release); }
    );

    // Start reading "asynchronously", wait for completion or timeout:
    std::atomic<boost::system::error_code> ec(boost::asio::error::would_block);
    size_t len = 0;

    boost::asio::async_read(sock, boost::asio::buffer(buffer + byteShift), boost::asio::transfer_exactly(bytesNeeded),
        [&, bytesNeeded](boost::system::error_code const& err, size_t bytesTransferred)
        {
            if (bytesTransferred != bytesNeeded) {
                std::cout << bytesTransferred << " , " << err.message() << std::endl;
            }
            len = bytesTransferred;
            ec.store(err, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    );

    do {
        io_service.run_one();
    } while (read_timeout.load(std::memory_order_acquire) != read_counter && // Continue if the **last** read didn't time out
        (ec.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == boost::asio::error::would_block) && // ec.store() not called,
        !io_service.stopped()); // and program still running.

    deadline.cancel(); // This will set read_timeout, if it wasn't set yet. But we ignore it from now on.

    if (ec.load(std::memory_order_acquire))
    {
        std::cerr << "oops\n"; // Real error handling omitted.
        throw std::runtime_error("");
    }
    else if (read_timeout == read_counter)
    {
        std::cerr << "timeout\n";
    }
    else if (len != bytesNeeded)
    {
        // This is the real problem.
        std::cerr << "Asked " << bytesNeeded << " got " << len;
    }
    return (int)len;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    do try {
        ::openSocket("192.168.6.30", "80");

        read(148); // Assume that data[] already has 364 bytes on the first call.
        for (;;)
        {
            read(512); // Full buffers on every subsequent call.
            // Do something with data[] here.
        }
    }
    catch (std::runtime_error) { } while (true);
}
```

The `do try catch while` is necessary because the error only happens after I unplug the other side. After the second call to `read(148)`, the next read(512)` fails.

[update]
It's not just `transfer_exactly`. With `transfer_at_least(512)` I also get the same problem, one superfluous 148 byte read. (The two should behave the same, as reading *at least* 512 bytes into a buffer that's *only* 512 bytes cannot read more or less bytes)

Comment: can you provide an [MCVE]? which boost version are you using?

Comment: Where does it say it is supposed to fill the buffer? All read methods are specified to return the number of bytes actually transferred precisely because they may *not* fill the buffer. In the case of a socket, if only 148 bytes arrive at a time, that is what you will get.

Comment: @EJP http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_exactly.html

Comment: If the supplied buffer becomes full, the `async_read()` can complete without error while reading less than `n` bytes when the `asio::transfer_exactly(n)` completion condition is provided.  Before initiating the second read, does `buffer_size(boost::asio::buffer(buffer))` equal 148?

Comment: @m.s. : Complete example, exhibiting the same problem. Boost version 1.57 actually, MSVC 2013. Source is a Boa embedded webserver.

Answer (score 0):

"Solved" it for now by ignoring the incorrect read operation. I was lucky in that I could deal with an unknown amount of missing data, and resync with the stream later on. But it looks like I will have to drop Boost::Asio in the future when I can no longer tolerate missed data.